# Have to run ruby script on Windows 7 and got Permission denied EACCES

Tags: ruby, windows

I have to run ruby script on windows 7 (I know that it's bad idea).
My script creates folders (if they is not exist) and copies files into them.
I'm using FileUtils lib to perform this job, like:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p(path)
FileUtils.cp_r(file.path, path)
FileUtils.touch(file)
```

On ubuntu and mac everything is ok, but on windows 7 machine I got next error:

```
Permission denied - ./program_folder/input/. (Errno::EACCES)
```

on this codeline:

```
Dir.entries('./program_folder/input').map { |file_name| File.new("./program_folder/input/#{file_name}") }.compact
```

Any ideas how can I fix it?

I have tried to run ruby and irb termianl with administrator access and tried to do FileUtils.chmod_R(0777, @path) on all paths but still no changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command

```
Dir.entries('./program_folder/input').map { |file_name| 
  File.new("./program_folder/input/#{file_name}")
}.compact
```

tries to create a File with the same name as the file/folder you read before.

In detail:

1. The first file found by `Dir.entries('.')` is the actual directory (`.`).
2. `"./program_folder/input/#{file_name}"` is `./program_folder/input/.` (an existing directory).
3. This directory path should be the path of a new file.
4. With `File.new` you can't open a directory as a File.

---

Remark after comment:

Inside the `Dir.entries` you call `File.new` - that creates a file handle. Without a mode, it tries to open an existing File (File, not Directory!). `.` is a directory which can't be opended as a file.

If you only want the filename, you don't need the `File.new`, the string `"./program_folder/input/#{file_name}"` would be enough. 
A better solution would be the `File.join` method:

```
File.join("./program_folder/input", file_name)
```

or

```
File.join(".", "program_folder", "input", file_name)
```

If you need on real filename, you can check for directories:

```
Dir.entries('./program_folder/input').map { |file_name|
  "./program_folder/input/#{file_name}" unless File.directory?("./program_folder/input/#{file_name}")
}.compact
```

or better, you remove the directories:

```
Dir.entries('.').delete_if{|file_name| 
  File.directory?(file_name)
}
```

Comment: I'm not overwriting files, I'm just create array with all file objects from this Dir.
"File.new Opens the file named by filename according to the given mode and returns a new File object."

Comment: See my edit. I think, I now understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I understand, I've removed '.' and '..' from list with simple checking: Dir.entries('./program_folder/input').map { |file_name| File.new("./program_folder/input/#{file_name}") unless file_name =~ /^\.\.?$/ }.compact
And now I have another error with Fileutils in 'utime' permission denied on this code: FileUtils.touch(file)

So, thank you!

Comment: You can find new issue by this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767883/fileutils-touch-in-windows-7